Swift SignalRClient, Hub connection failing yet using same url/auth token works fine using the Microsoft java signal R package
Im attempting to implement a signal R client into a swift app (https://github.com/moozzyk/SignalR-Client-Swift), although when attempting to connect to the hub using an auth token it errors out. The debug outputs:
2024-05-10T15:01:56.793Z debug: HttpConnection init
2024-05-10T15:01:56.794Z debug: HubConnection init
2024-05-10T15:01:56.795Z info: Starting hub connection
2024-05-10T15:01:56.795Z info: Starting reconnectable connection
2024-05-10T15:01:56.795Z debug: Attempting to change state from: 'disconnected' to: 'starting'
2024-05-10T15:01:56.796Z debug: Changing state to: 'starting' succeeded
2024-05-10T15:01:56.797Z debug: Starting or reconnecting
2024-05-10T15:01:56.797Z debug: HttpConnection init
2024-05-10T15:01:56.797Z debug: HttpConnection deinit
2024-05-10T15:01:56.797Z info: Starting connection
2024-05-10T15:01:56.797Z debug: Attempting to change state from: 'initial' to: 'connecting'
2024-05-10T15:01:56.797Z debug: Changing state to: 'connecting' succeeded
2024-05-10T15:01:57.814Z debug: HubConnection deinit
2024-05-10T15:01:59.579Z debug: Negotiate completed with OK status code
2024-05-10T15:01:59.579Z debug: Negotiate response: {"negotiateVersion":1,"connectionId":"IFs4vc68Yk-zz9Yv4qFfjQ","connectionToken":"LEIXPU-uZ5qwXdBQGbILtg","availableTransports":[{"transport":"WebSockets","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]},{"transport":"ServerSentEvents","transferFormats":["Text"]},{"transport":"LongPolling","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]}]}
2024-05-10T15:01:59.580Z debug: Negotiation response received
2024-05-10T15:01:59.581Z info: Selected WebSockets transport
2024-05-10T15:01:59.581Z info: Starting WebSocket transport
2024-05-10T15:01:59.582Z debug: HttpConnection deinit
2024-05-10T15:01:59.650Z debug: (ws) no auth challenge handler registered - falling back to default handling
2024-05-10T15:01:59.721Z info: urlSession didOpenWithProtocol invoked. WebSocket open
Connection 2: received failure notification
nw_read_request_report [C2] Receive failed with error "Socket is not connected"
nw_flow_service_reads [C2 188.212.124.141:443 failed parent-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, ipv6, dns, uses wifi)] No output handler
nw_flow_add_write_request [C2 188.212.124.141:443 failed parent-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, ipv6, dns, uses wifi)] cannot accept write requests
nw_write_request_report [C2] Send failed with error "Socket is not connected"
2024-05-10T15:02:14.731Z debug: urlSession didCloseWith invoked
2024-05-10T15:02:14.731Z debug: urlSession didCompleteWithError invoked
2024-05-10T15:02:14.731Z debug: error is nil - ignoring error
2024-05-10T15:02:14.731Z info: WebSocket close. Code: 1000, reason:
2024-05-10T15:02:14.732Z debug: Marking transport as closed.
To rule out it being an issue with the server, I made an android app using Microsofts official Java package. When attempting to connect to the Hub in the Java application using the same url and token, it was successful
In the swift app I have tried using both headers and accesstokenprovider options to pass the token but yet cannot connect to the signalR server
Swift code is:
func setupSignalR() {
        let atoken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0eXAiOiJhdXRoIiwic3ViIjoiMDc2M2VhMmItZjVjNi00NTBiLTlhNGQtZTE0MTcxMTUyMzZlIiwibmFtZSI6InJlc2lkZW50MiIsImVtYWlsIjoibC5zdXRlckB0bGpncm91cC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE3MTUzNTQzNjEsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20vd3MvMjAwOC8wNi9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvcm9sZSI6IlJlc2lkZW50IiwiZXhwIjoxNzE1MzU1NTYxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3ZpZGVvLWNoYXQtYXBpLm9za2kuc2l0ZTo0NDMiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3ZpZGVvLWNoYXQub3NraS5zaXRlOjQ0MyJ9.PqVn68dnpAZZ83ewPbqCdeZbG92b-Vxp8A6Yo-Blm4k"
        
        let Url = "https://video-chat-api.oski.site/call-hub"
        
        let hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder(url: URL(string: Url)!)
            .withHttpConnectionOptions(configureHttpOptions: { (options) in
                options.accessTokenProvider = { return atoken}
                //options.headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(atoken)"]
            })
            .withLogging(minLogLevel: .debug)
            .build()
        
        hubConnection.start()
    }

Java code is:
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnection;
import com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnectionBuilder;
import com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnectionState;

import java.util.UUID;

import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String url = "https://video-chat-api.oski.site/call-hub";
    String token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0eXAiOiJhdXRoIiwic3ViIjoiMDc2M2VhMmItZjVjNi00NTBiLTlhNGQtZTE0MTcxMTUyMzZlIiwibmFtZSI6InJlc2lkZW50MiIsImVtYWlsIjoibC5zdXRlckB0bGpncm91cC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE3MTUzNTQzNjEsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20vd3MvMjAwOC8wNi9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvcm9sZSI6IlJlc2lkZW50IiwiZXhwIjoxNzE1MzU1NTYxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3ZpZGVvLWNoYXQtYXBpLm9za2kuc2l0ZTo0NDMiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3ZpZGVvLWNoYXQub3NraS5zaXRlOjQ0MyJ9.PqVn68dnpAZZ83ewPbqCdeZbG92b-Vxp8A6Yo-Blm4k";
    HubConnection hubConnection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create(url)
                .withAccessTokenProvider(Single.defer(() -> Single.just(token)))
                .build();

        hubConnection.on("ReceiveCall", (callId, offer) -> {
            Log.i("SignalR", "Incoming Call");
        }, String.class, String.class);

        hubConnection.on("CallMemberRemoved", () -> {
            // Handle call member removal
        });

        hubConnection.on("ReceiveCandidate", (candidate) -> {
            // Handle received candidate
        }, String.class);

        hubConnection.start().blockingAwait();

        listenCalls();
    }

    public void listenCalls() {
        hubConnection.send("ListenCalls");
    }

    public void joinCall(UUID callId, String answer) {
        hubConnection.send("JoinCall", callId, answer);
    }

    public void leaveCall(UUID callId) {
        hubConnection.send("LeaveCall", callId);
    }

    public void sendCandidate(UUID callId, String candidate) {
        hubConnection.send("SendCandidate", callId, candidate);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hubConnection.close();
    }
}

